# Number of Hours Between Two Dates Not Working in Excel

Tags: excel

As requested, I have included a simplified screenshot that illustrates the issue.

[image]

As you can see, I subtracted the two dates and formatted it as "h:mm:ss".  Why doesn't this give you the total amount of hours that have passed between the two dates?  Is there a better way to do this?  There is a great answer below, but I am trying to figure out why doing the way illustrated in this screenshot doesn't work.

### **END OF EDIT**

I am aware that similar questions have been answered here, but for whatever reason this is not working for me at all.

I have two columns: one is a date, one is the time.

[image]

As you can see from the currently highlighted cell, the "time" column is actually stored as date with the time included.  In column H, I have the date stored as a serial code so that the decimal number refers to a month, day, year, hour, minute, and second.  When I subtract the serial code that refers to 2/16/2016 3:20:01 PM from the serial code that refers to refers to 2/14/2016 1:20:01 PM and format that cell as "h:mm", I am getting 2:00.  Why?????

I have been hacking away at this for a while and this is supposed to be stupid easy and it's not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated so I can move on to more important things.

Comment: There are more than 2 hours between the 14th of February and the 16th of February.  Am I not asking this properly?

Comment: It's okay.  I have no idea what to do and this starting to really frustrate me.  Why doesn't this work??

Comment: _There are more than 2 hours between the 14th of February and the 16th of February. Am I not asking this properly?_ It's not really clear what you are asking about, there's a table with too many rows and columns on the screenshot. Create one with only 3 values - A, B, C, format it to show full values and ask why A-B<>C

Comment: I think you are getting bogged down with Excel's formatting, which admittedly can mask what is really going on underneath the hood.

Comment: Is it possible that your formatting is simply discarding the day-difference?

Comment: @BrakNicku I am updating it now.  Please go have another look.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman yes it is not paying attention to the day-difference.  Why is it doing this?  The answer below is great, but I am still curious as to why it does this and what other ways there are around it.  I'm a very curious person haha

Comment: Yeah, the "h" in format is explicitly 0-23. You do need [h] to cover longer durations. (See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work.  Just take the difference between the two dates, format the cell containing the difference as `Number`, and then use one of the following formulas to get the units you want.  I will assume that:

`A1` has the value `2/16/2016 3:20:01 PM`

`B1` has the value `2/14/2016 1:20:01 PM`

Into `C1` enter `A1 - B1`, and format it as `Number`

If you want the difference as days, leave `C1` as is.
If you want hours, use `=24*(A1 - B1)`
If you want minutes, use `=24*60*(A1 - B1)`
If you want seconds, use `=24*60*60*(A1 - B1)`

Comment: I really appreciate this.  The question I have now is, why doesn't doing it the way I was doing it work?  Meaning, what was Excel doing?  It looked like what it was doing was just subtracting the number of hour that were included in those dates and not taking into account the number of days.  Why was it doing that?

Comment: @Ryan_C This is a good question.  Since you formatted the cell as `H:SS` my guess is that Excel only looks at the hour and second portions of the two cells involved in the difference.  The day components are ignored completely, leaving you with a difference of `2:00` (2 hours), even though there were also 2 full days between the cells.

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER TO THIS IS REALLY SILLY.

Below, you will find that Tim Biegeleisen provided an excellent answer to this question.  I just wanted to further elaborate.

Sometimes having too many option for formatting can be a problem, which is what happened here.

When you subtract `2/14/2016 1:20:01 PM` from `2/16/2016 3:20:01 PM` and format it as `h:mm:ss` it only subtracts the hours portion and ignores days.  You just have to somehow know that if you are trying to do what I'm trying to do, you have to format it as `[h]:mm:ss` and then it will calculate the total number of hours passed.  The bracket around the "h" is the important part here.  I hope this helps the next person who comes across this.